# How to make byobu automatically select last used session?

Tags: byobu

More often than not, I just want the last session I was using in byobu, and if I want a different one, the hotkeys make navigating to it relatively friction-free. So I'm wondering if there's a way to skip the session selection menu and go straight to the last used session?